# C# - Find all email addresses for an Active Directory user

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm trying to get all the email addresses associated to a given AD user.

For the user I have the domain and the login name (ex. DOMAIN\UserName) and I the AD is storing the email addresses in:

1. The mail attribute.
2. In `proxyAddresses` attributes.

So far, I don't know what C# API to use to connect to the AD, and how to properly filter by the user to fetch all the email addresses. I'm using .NET 3.5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 34):

Here's a possible solution using various classes in the [`System.DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace.

```
string username = "username";
string domain = "domain";

List<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>();

PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, username);

// Add the "mail" entry
emailAddresses.Add(user.EmailAddress);

// Add the "proxyaddresses" entries.
PropertyCollection properties = ((DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties;
foreach (object property in properties["proxyaddresses"])
{
   emailAddresses.Add(property.ToString());
}
```

Comment: A reference to "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" is also needed for this example to work.

Comment: +1 This is better than the accepted answer because a) you don't have to leave this site to get help and b) it doesn't have all the cryptic LDAP query stuff.

Comment: I would respectfully disagree - while this adds some clarity, it doesn't point out an important distinction that this documentation fails to point out: "this [proxyAddress] property lists all email address types, such as SMTP, x.400, etc.  So we will need to modify our code to check for the SMTP type". Furthermore, and perhaps Microsoft is to blame here for invalid documentation, @Donut - I am still left wondering why you did the following:

emailAddresses.Add(user.EmailAddress)

when the Microsoft docs define this attribute as "the list of email addresses for a contact" (multiple addresses?)

Comment: In my case I was simply looking for an individuals email address using "username".  I was able to get exactly what I wanted by using 
userEmail = user.EmailAddress;

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the DirectoryEntry class.
You can pull properties from there given you have the LDAP string set up.  The propery for mail is "mail" ironic aint it ?