# Transforming incoming username claim in ADFS when doing active authentication

Tags: c#, active-directory, adfs2.0, adfs

I'm attempting to authenticate to an ADFS server via active federation, but need to transform the incoming username via an AD/LDAP query before attempting to authenticate the user.

I'm using the UsernameMixed endpoint with a UserNameWSTrustBinding:

```
WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), "https://nobody.com/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed");          

factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue, WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer);
SecurityToken token = channel.Issue(rst);
```

My problem is, I want to transform the "username" passed to the endpoing to the user's email address (via AD or LDAP) on the ADFS server before running authentication.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: The scenario doesn't make sense to me as I understand it, combined with how I understand "Active" authentication with ADFS (or any STS). If your relying party application has access to the AD server where ALL of your users will come from, then why would you worry about federation or ADFS at all? Why not just set up your app for integrated (windows) authentication? If you need to query the AD to get some value (anything at all) then all benefits of federated authentication are completely void.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no simple way on the AD FS server to transform the incoming username before doing authentication.  The transformations are done on outgoing claims after authentication has already happened.

You'll probably need to query AD/LDAP in your relying party application to get this information.  Do something like this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609353/c-sharp-find-all-email-addresses-for-an-active-directory-user)):

```
string domain = "YourDomain";

List<string> emailAddresses = new List<string>();

PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName);

// Add the "mail" entry
emailAddresses.Add(user.EmailAddress);

// Add the "proxyaddresses" entries.
PropertyCollection properties = ((DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties;
foreach (object property in properties["proxyaddresses"])
{
   emailAddresses.Add(property.ToString());
}
```