# How to retrieve current logged in user credentials and use to send an email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have a function for sending email.

My requirement is, I need to send the email using the credentials of currently logged in windows user (Active Directory).

I have used this code.

```
 public ActionResult Mail2()
    {

        string From = "Vik.m@example.com";
        string To = Request.Form["TotxtBox"];
        string CC = Request.Form["CCtxtBox"];
        string Subject = Request.Form["Subject"];
        string body = Request.Form["BodytxtArea"];

        MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage(From,To);
        objMailMessage.Subject = Subject;
        objMailMessage.Body = body;
        objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

        SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        objSmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        objSmtpClient.Host = "Hostname@host.com";
        objSmtpClient.Port = 25;
        objSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
        objSmtpClient.Credentials = credential;
        objSmtpClient.Send(objMailMessage);
        Return view();
}
```

I just want to pass currently logged in user's windows username and password in the given field. Is there a way to retrieve those. Can anyone Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just put the SMTP details in your `web.config` file like so:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="support@host.com">
            <!--<network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="accountforemailtesting@gmail.com" password="Abc.1234" />-->

            <network host="Hostname@host.com" port="25" userName="" password="" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

And then from code, you can just use the `SmtpClient` class to send the email. The code may look like:

```
private void SendMessage(string emailId, string subject, string body)
{
    var msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailId));
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
    smtpClient.Send(msg);
}
```

You may want to use a google account for testing and once email testing is done, switch to your company server details as shown in above `web.config`.

**Update**

OP says

> I want who ever login to this software, their system username password
>   will go instead of this unique id and password.

You can get username using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name but not password. You will have to ask application user to provide one. In that case you will have to capture the username and password while they login and use it in your Mail2() method. Whoever calling this method should supply that information.

I am not sure if this is the route you should go. The email should go from logged in user email ID but the SMTP account details typically stays the same. You care retrieve email ID of current logged in user as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913271/getting-email-address-from-active-directory).

Comment: I can do this,but problem is that It become common username password for all. I want who ever login to this software, their system username password will go instead of this unique id and password.. I hope u got it..

Comment: O I see, in that case you will have to capture the username and password while they login and use it in your Mail2() method. Whoever calling this method should supply that information.

Comment: is that possible to get windows username and password, because for my application windows username password will be same for mailing also.

Comment: You mean active directory?

Comment: You can get username using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name but not password. You will have to ask application user to provide one.

Comment: yeah..in Active Directory

Comment: Once you have the credentials, supply it in System.Net.NetworkCredential("ADUsername", "ADPassword"); Try with your own credentials.

Comment: yeah its working if I give credential, but how to get windows username and password that's my actual question.

Comment: I am editing your question, may be someone else will help. I dont know a way to retrieve password.

Comment: yeah..thanks a lot these knowledgeable conversation.